# Background operation and ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-asynctask

I created an `AsyncTask` to perform my background operation. The UI shows a `ProgressDialog`. I pass the `Context` to the constructor of the `AsyncTask`.

When I want to manipulate the the `ProgressDialog` text from `AsyncTask` it errors because the `ProgressDialog` box is created by a different thread.

Tips or ideas on how I can make the `AsyncTask` communicate with the `ProgressDialog` box, or a better way to create the `ProgressDialog` box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't communicate with UI from `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` function. Use `onProgressUpdate` function instead.

```
private class BackgrounTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... count){
       int max = count[0];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         publishProgress(i, max);
       }
       return max;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
       int cur = progress[0];
       int max = progress[1];

       //update your progress dialog here
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
       //process result
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it working, thank you for the question edit and the awnser!

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask.publishProgress()` method and override `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` method. In this method update your progress dialog.